# Triaging items according to a time threshold

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm having this part of code which I want to make smaller, more readable and easy to manage. Any thoughts? I tried linq but got lost.

```
foreach (var o in state.s)
        {
            TimeSpan timeDiff = (DateTime.Now - o.time);
            if (timeDiff.TotalSeconds < 300)
            {
                richTextBox.AppendColoredText(o.name + " ", Color.Green);
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox.AppendColoredText(o.name + " ", Color.Red);
                if (f == false)
                {
                    listA.Add(o.name);
                    listA_clone.Add(o.name);
                }
                else
                {
                    listA.Add(o._name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The only thing I see that could reduce the amount of lines is the inner `else` statement. It's not necessary. You could have `listA.Add(o._name);` outside the `if` and remove the `else`part

Comment: That's true @ClaudioRedi but i was hoping for some linq/lamda expression which would make this hole think a line or two. My issue is that i need to copy this for each and have around 100 for many objects.

Comment: If you have to do the same thing for each of them why not make it into a void?

Comment: @maam27 the objects are different in type and values but with the same methods. Could you show an example? I was wondering if i could do something like `pass(state); //state is the obj` and then at the method use it like `public void pass(object obj) { foreach (var o in obj.s) {//stuff here.} }`

Comment: You *never* ought to copy the code. Instead, factor out what's common into a new function that takes parameters for all the parts that are different.

Answer (score 4):

> *I tried linq but got lost.*

LINQ stands for *Language-INtegrated **Query*** - and *querying* objects (or data) is not something that should have side-effects... and the very purpose of that loop *is* to have side-effects. In other words, using LINQ here would be abusing the language.

---

Your usage of `var` is inconsistent, and the naming is... dangerous - I like `var`, a lot. So I like that you're having it in your loop declaration. You see, I can *guess* that `timeDiff` is a `TimeSpan` just by looking at its name - and its assignment makes it pretty obvious what the type is as well. But I have no clue whatsoever what an `o` is, and all I know about `s` is that it's probably an `IEnumerable<whatever-the-type-of-o-is>`. Readable code is code that one can... *read*.

`o.time` and `o.name` are confusing, because they don't follow the typical `PascalCase` naming convention for public members. If they're public property getters, they should be `o.Time` and `o.Name`.

`o._name` is confusing *at best*, and a clear violation of encapsulation at worst. `_name` looks very much like a name for a private field - which shouldn't be accessible from this code. And if it's a public field, then you've broken encapsulation (because fields should never be `public`). And if `_name` isn't the backing field for the `name` property, then you have another problem: you clearly aren't writing code *as if the next maintainer were a violent psychopath that knows where you live*:

```
listA.Add(o.name);
...
listA.Add(o._name);
```

Another thing to note, is that the *Boolean expression* in an `if` condition doesn't need to involve a comparison against a Boolean value here:

```
if (f == false)
```

if `f` is a `bool`, then `if (!f)` *is* a Boolean expression... that would be perfectly clear if `f` had a meaningful name. By convention `bool` variable names start with `is`, or `has`:

```
if (!isHairyCode)
```

or

```
if (!hasBugs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a clearly stated goal.  You want a smaller, more readable loop, if possible.  Part of the more readable part of C# is adhering to certain conventions.  Things of note:

**Property** names should be Pascal cased with the first letter capitalized, i.e. "Name" instead of "name".

**Underscores** should be reserved as private class-level fields.  You reference both o.name and o._name.  Either that's a typo or worse, more confusing to someone as to why you have 2 variables so closely named the same.  Usually the underscore is reserved for a backing field to a public property.

**Brackets** usually are on their own line without extra indentation.  Rare exception: one-liners.

Using `var` for declaration where the type becomes obvious.  So your

```
TimeSpan timeDiff = (DateTime.Now - o.time);
```

becomes

```
var timeDiff = (DateTime.Now - o.time);
```

However, since that value is referenced only once, and its simple enough to express, I would suggest it does not need its own variable.  Admittedly when attempting to make code shorter and more readable, one should avoid being overly terse as it makes the original coders intentions harder to follow.

When evaluating Boolean variables in a conditional, there is no need to use true or false.  So `(f == false)` can simply be `(!f)`.

If your `_name` is not a typo, then your code really needs refactoring before restructuring.  ***Assuming*** the `_name` was a typo, you could shorten your code (but not by much):

```
foreach (var o in state.s)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - o.time).TotalSeconds < 300)
    {
        richTextBox.AppendColoredText(o.name + " ", Color.Green);
    }
    else
    {
        richTextBox.AppendColoredText(o.name + " ", Color.Red);
        listA.Add(o.name);
        if (!f) { listA_clone.Add(o.name); }
    }
}
```

But that is only if `o._name` is a typo.

**Additional:**

Besides the confusion over `o.name` and `o._name`, I also can't help but wonder is `state.s` is a typo.  This could be easier to read if rather than a one-letter lower-cased property name you refactored to a more meaning name, e.g. `state.SomethingMeaningful` or `state.SelectedItems`.  Or did you intend for it to be simlply `states`?

Futhermore, where does the f come from?  Apparently its external to your code snippet.  It has no contextual meaning.  It should have a fuller, more descriptive name.

Following my own suggestions except for `f`, I would expect to see code such as:

```
foreach (var state in states)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - state.Time).TotalSeconds < 300)
    {
        richTextBox.AppendColoredText(state.Name + " ", Color.Green);
    }
    else
    {
        richTextBox.AppendColoredText(state.Name + " ", Color.Red);
        listA.Add(state.Name);
        if (!f) { listA_clone.Add(state.Name); }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
foreach (var item in state.SelectedItems)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - item.Time).TotalSeconds < 300)
    {
        richTextBox.AppendColoredText(item.Name + " ", Color.Green);
    }
    else
    {
        richTextBox.AppendColoredText(item.Name + " ", Color.Red);
        listA.Add(item.Name);
        if (!f) { listA_clone.Add(item.Name); }
    }
}
```

Depending upon your actual intent.  But that's the main point: your intent is hard to follow from your code.  Choose better names for better clarity and less confusion.

Comment: This answer lack sufficient explanation to constitute a Code Review answer. Also, the code is not equivalent to the original.

Comment: @200_success Duly noted and my answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: For property names it is `PascalCase` casing instead of `camelCase` casing ;-)

Answer (score -2):

I always like to put my brackets with the statement, instead of giving every single bracket a line for itself, Like this:

```
foreach (var o in state.s) {
        TimeSpan timeDiff = (DateTime.Now - o.time);
        if (timeDiff.TotalSeconds < 300) {
            richTextBox.AppendColoredText(o.name + " ", Color.Green);
        } else {
            richTextBox.AppendColoredText(o.name + " ", Color.Red);
            if (f == false) {
                listA.Add(o.name);
                listA_clone.Add(o.name);
            } else {
                listA.Add(o._name);
            }
        }
    }
```

This might not be what you are looking for, But it is smaller

Comment: Visual studio takes care of brackets automatically.

Comment: Not to start a Holy War, but C# bracing convention puts the scope-opening brace on the next line. What you have here looks like Java code.